# ABP.net Google Login Authentication

Tags: c#, abp

Login Data in Json Format come as :

```
{
   "access_token":"ya29.AWY7Ckn6TdohIO0PFJmYXte_HT4XPLWUjqAtzvT6NRBJP-Y9mCltr8VyXc9B6TfKzflAZL9thzY0GO-212B80PQ5GsFJ4Qo3ESSpg0dMWDYRgC0PhZCMbusFwOtWutEyoe2yG92hC3BUn-T2QsuwwFmaGOaCgYKAXISARISFQG1tDrpzNmP31KT7-ILOwBzIRP8pg0163",
   "token_type":"Bearer",
   "expires_in":3599,
   "scope":"email profile openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
   "authuser":"2",
   "hd":"example.com",
   "prompt":"consent",
   "sub":"113906241569794417263",
   "name":"Test Subject",
   "given_name":"Test",
   "family_name":"Subject",
   "picture":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/cHTtcEpKxcejzUdDn-UJgTWe4eeLeeS3jCk_8UPIS7=s96-c",
   "email":"Test.Subject@example.com",
   "email_verified":true,
   "locale":"en"
}
```

How to handle those JSON data to authenticate in ABP.net framework. When I researched, I got the outcome as ABP.net automatically handles the login process. But I want to learn the processes and codes in ABP.net

Tried learning from the Youtube video https://youtu.be/W4tmb_LKxe8
but nothing is solved